# matlab, plot multiple matrices different colors

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

Within my GUI I want to plot multiple matrices on the same plot in different colors.  The matrices are being combined from .mat files within different folders so I am currently saving them within a structure.  How can I tell the plotter to plot each matrix a different color and  symbol?  Thanks

Edit:

I was trying to use

```
plot(1:size(small_group,1),small_group,'.')
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1 0 0;0 1 0]);
```

However this changed the color for every line.  I also haven't worked much with adjusting the symbol yet.

I manually added multiple matrices within the structure by,

```
plot(small_group_struct(1,2).values)
hold on; plot(small_group_struct(1,1).values)
```

I was hoping to be able to use the `set(0,'DefaultAxesColor', [1 0 0; 0 1 0], ...
        'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder','-|--|:|-.');` to adjust the color and symbol but it is changing the color/symbol for every column not matrix.

Comment: What have you tried to far? Have you tried to experiment with the options of the plot command?

Comment: Edited the OP with what I have tried

Comment: Do you mean `plot(mat1, 'r'); hold on; plot(mat2, 'g');` ?

Comment: @peter, that is how I have tested it in the command window.  However, this GUI the user selects how many files or matrices to be plotted so the number could vary.  I am trying to refrain from hard coding too much as i'm worried it could result in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the syntax

```
plot(mat1, 'r');
hold on;
plot(mat2, 'g');
```

However, instead of hardcoding the values, compute them from your own table:

```
mystyles = {'r-', 'g:', 'k|'};

plotstyle = mystyles{mod(plotnum, length)+1};
plot(values, plotstyle);
```

I've used `mod` to circle back around the beginning.  You can use whatever logic you want, including combining different colors and styles with two different pieces of arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
aa=gca;
for i=1:N
plot(mat(:,:,i),'color',aa.ColorOrder(aa.ColorOrderIndex,:))
end
```

it will set the same color to all the lines in the same matrix.